# Passing enum flags to a class or procedure

Tags: vb.net, enums, enum-flags

I would like to pass multiple enum (bitwise) items to a procedure. Not separately but and'd together similar to the Messagebox command. eg:

```
MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel
```

There's plenty of info on the Flagg option etc but not on how to pass as single combined variable

In vs2019 I have setup the enum

```
<Flags>
Public Enum Options 
    n = 0
    Check = 1
    Print = 2
    Mail = 4    
End
```

and my function is

```
Public Function MyMsg(Text As String, MsgOption As Options) As boolean
```

all good, and when I attempt to write the call

```
 MyMsg("Lorem  luctus non", Options.Print + Options.Mail)
```

I get
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'MyMsg' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Function MyMsg(Text As String, MsgOption As Options) As Boolean': Argument matching parameter 'MsgOption' narrows from 'Integer' to 'Options'

I don't want to create the function with integer otherwise I lose the intellisense showing enum options, again similar to MessageBox.

I can see the issue (narrows from 'Integer' to 'Options') but cant see how to pass the values.

Can any of you guys/gels help ?

Comment: Try calling it like this `MyMsg("Lorem  luctus non", Options.Print Or Options.Mail)`

Comment: Supper Fast Response, Thanks 
Yes that seems to work !<br> So how has Microsoft done it ?

Comment: Take a look at the binary representations of those numeric values and then find out how a bitwise OR operation actually works and you'll see.

Comment: Just as a hint there's a BitArray and a BitVector32 class. The other approch will still work too.

Comment: Im happy with the bit wise operator, this is why the enums are all powers of 2. But it just sieems simple the way Microsoft have done it by allowing the + operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either of these two methods: Both worked in vs 2019.

```
MyMsg("Lorem luctus non", Options.Print Or Options.Mail)
```

Or

```
MyMsg("Lorem luctus non", CType(Options.Mail + Options.Print + Options.Check, Options))
```

Comment: hadent tought of using Ctype to force it back to the Options type. But the MS Message box can still use the + operator, Any ideas how they have done it ?

Comment: How did you use the plus operator in ms message box ?

Comment: Ahh not so much MessageBox but MsgBox , but still the same thing MsgBox("Hello World", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Title") which is what ive used all over. I have now tried MessageBox and that dosent like the +

Comment: You do not have option strict on. Do you?

Comment: I checked and no it was not, as soon as I set it on same thing with msgbox, don't suppose you can expand on it a little ?  Thanks